# Importing from function via loop to a single data frame

Tags: function, loops, dataframe, import

I'm new to R programming. I have a function that imports trimestral data on a survey from a website to work with in R. The function from the package eph is as follows:

get_microdata(year = 2019, trimester = 2 , type = "individual")

I need to create a loop to import the corresponding data from year 2012 on for each trimester to a single data frame so as to be able to see the evolution of the individual variables throughout time.

I got this idea in a previous post:

Maybe something like: get_microdata2 <- function(x) {get_microdata(year = 2019, trimester = x , type = "individual")}; lapply(1:3, get_microdata2)

this is actually very useful, but I can´t figure out how to convert this to a data frame nor can I figure out how to write a function to "loop" the trimester as well as the year. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks! 
Best!

Answer (score 0):

the `get_microdata()` function has been updated and now you can get more than one trimestral data at once:

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(eph)

# Get the data
base_individual <- get_microdata(year = 2018:2019,
                                 trimester = 1:2,
                                 type='individual') %>% 
  select(microdata) %>%
  unnest(microdata)

# Check
calculate_tabulates(base_individual, "TRIMESTRE", "ANO4")
```

For more features: https://holatam.github.io/eph/